# HibernateJPaVendorAdapter :Cannot convert value of type String to required type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database' ENitty

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-entitymanager, spring-orm

I have configured my entityManagerFactory in spring xml file something like :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="tesDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="${tes.db.database:ORACLE}"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="${tes.db.showSql:false}"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${tes.db.generateDdl:false}"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${tes.db.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

But I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database' for property 'database': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I really intend to default this property to ORACLE. Please help me with it.

Comment: I dont' think that you nee this at all:  <property name="database" value="${tes.db.database:ORACLE}"/>

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Why? I do need it as I have vendor options and I intend to default it to ORACLE if this property is not defined

Comment: Which version of Spring and HIbernate do you use? Spring/Hibernate do recognize the DB base on the JDBC string.